Background color from style is not applied to button when applied by kotlin
I have a style defined like that:
<style name="ButtonStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/green</item>
</style>

When using it in the XML with style="@style/ButtonStyle", it works fine.
But, when using it programmatically, it does fully works. The text color is well applied, but the background stay the default one instead of beeing green.
Here is the code that create button:
val button = Button(context, null, 0, R.style.ButtonStyle)
button.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
button.text = text
layout.addView(button)

I tried:

Using Button(ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.ButtonStyle), null, 0, R.style.ButtonStyle) : Same result
Trying to use button.setBackgroundResource() but R.style.ButtonStyle is not a resource ID
Searched for style parameters in the button, but I didn't find anything

How can I make the background style be applied ?
